# HSQL - Intermittent exception while retrieving data from HSQL DB

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQL DB for my unit testing. For one of the test, I want to retrieve data from a table & validate that. I populate this table before running that test. But sometimes this test case pass and sometimes it throws following error. This behavior is intermittent & I am not able to find the cause of this error.

**Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find XxX.XXX.XXX.EntityTypeMapped with id 12**

I am using HSQL 2.3.2. Appreciate any help in this regard

Thanks

Comment: With file: databases, perform a checkpoint after populating to ensure persistence.

Comment: But if the data is not persisted then my Junit will anyway fail.

Comment: The data always gets persisted with a CHECKPOINT execution.